# Exactly when the session will expire in java web application with tomcat

Tags: java, session

I am using tomcat server while developing web application.I see one situation today.
   I stopped the server and after 5 seconds started again.Then the previous session was not 
  expired .What is the reason for that.Exactly when the session will expire?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you cleared your browser's cache and then checked if the session variables still exist?

Comment: but i did not cleared the history

Comment: don't forget to restart the browser

Comment: when i stop the server what will happen for the session

Comment: the session will  be destroyed, but since you didn't restart your browser, you are still served values from browser's cache imparting an impression that the session is still in session :)

Comment: @Satya If you look to your pojos why they are all serializable?

Comment: By default time is 30 min and developer can change this time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down normally and restarted, or when an
>   application reload is triggered, the standard Manager implementation
>   will attempt to serialize all currently active sessions to a disk file
>   located via the pathname attribute. All such saved sessions will then
>   be deserialized and activated (assuming they have not expired in the
>   mean time) when the application reload is completed.

This is a quote from Tomcat 7 docs [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts)

You can turn off this behavior by changing the configuration in context.xml:

```
<Manager>
   ...
   <saveOnRestart>false</saveOnRestart> (by default is true)
</Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this by setting a saveOnRestart flag in your context.xml file of server.
Try adding the below lines to your conext.xml file`

```
           <Manager pathname="">
                    <saveOnRestart>false</saveOnRestart>
            </Manager>
```

`